# Reading values from txt file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I like to read all value from a txt file and store e.g :
    20,110,60,140
    10,210,80,240
    and store the values e.g

```
 id[0] = 20 , id[1] = 110 , id[2] = 60 , id[3] = 140 and
 id1[0] = 10 , id1[1] = 210 , id1[2] = 80 , id[3] = 240
```

how can I change my code below to get values in a format discussed above

```
def main():
  # Txt read
  global id
  id=[]
  input = open('log.txt', 'r')
  for eachLine in input:
    substrs = eachLine.split(',', eachLine.count(','))
    for strVar in substrs:
      if strVar.isdigit():
        id.append(int(strVar))

main()
print(id[3])`
```

Comment: what if 2 lines , how you want to return output ?

Comment: I am reading file with input values in 2 lines as line1 = 20,110,60,140 and line2 = 10,210,80,240, just want line 1 values to be stored as id[] and line 2 as id1[],

Comment: it will be very complex if you want to create dynamic variables like id, id1,id2 , so doing with a dict or list of list will be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating dynamic variables is a bad idea, so you can try like this :

```
f = open("log.txt", "r")
ids = []
for i in f.readlines():
    sub_id = list(map(int,i.split(",")))
    ids.append(sub_id)
print(ids)
# [[20, 110, 60, 140],[10, 210, 80, 24]]
```

or :

```
f = open("log.txt", "r")
ids = {}
for j,i in enumerate(f.readlines()):
    sub_id = list(map(int,i.split(",")))
    ids['id'+str(j)] = sub_id
print(ids)
# {'id1': [10, 210, 80, 24], 'id0': [20, 110, 60, 140]}
```

Comment: Thankyou, now how I can print a subid in for example id1?

Comment: in first eg: you can do like `ids[1][index you want to show]` , and in dict `ids['id1'][index you want to show]`